# Hiding Direct IP of the websites dedicated server from google search

Tags: .htaccess

Ok, so we have a website and game server that is protected with a proxy to combat massive DDOS attacks that we have had in the past. So it is a problem that when people google the name of the server it results in a top result being the dedicated servers IP address. I googled this for a few hours and came up with the solution being adding conditions to the .htaccess file. Which still has solved my problem. What I have in .htaccess is below:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host) !^198.12.xxx.xxx/ [nc]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forums.empiresmc.net/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
```

Is that correct? Or am I going about this solution in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `RewriteCond %{http_host) !^198.12.xxx.xxx/` will work (assuming xxx is a real number). There are mismatching brackets and `/` at the end is also a problem.

Have your rule like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^forums\.empiresmc\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://forums.empiresmc.net/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Rather than checking for IP it is checking whether HOST_NAME is not `forums.empiresmc.net` in the request.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I actually already had that one as well, but mine differed a little bit. Do you know about how long that takes to update?

Comment: .htaccess is active immediately and these rules will perform as designed. However after you've made `R=301` above it will take some time for search engines to update their result. In my experience I've see that it may take upto 1 month for search engines to updated it.